# Completely disappeared Wireless

Tags: wireless, networking

Some days ago after partial upgrade and update my "Ubuntu 12.04 64bit" wireless disappeared.

I googled and tried several solutions such as:

1.BIOS Reset

2.Re-installing all packages related to wireless via Synaptic.

3.Re-installing `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

4.Running this command via terminal `sudo rfkill unblock all`.

But none have any effect. Now with `rfkill list all` I can see that:

```
soft block=0
hard block=0
```

In section Wireless LAN,
so it is ok.
In additional drivers section I see disabled Broadcom STA Wireless driver, and try enable it, but it gives error with long log in file  `/var/log/jockey.log`

**Important fact:** My hardware is OK as I have tried to use WiFi via LiveCD and it worked. So the problem is in my Ubuntu 12.04.

But what else can I do?
Wireless option has just disappeared from network window.
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> doesn't do anything, the wireless light is always turned `OFF`.

When I write `ifconfig` in terminal, it doesn't show Wlan as it showed before. It gives this code:

```
$ ifconfig

bnep0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:00:4e:12:2a:24  
          inet addr:192.168.44.88  Bcast:192.168.44.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9200:4eff:fe12:2a24/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23059 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20570 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18550526 (18.5 MB)  TX bytes:3535892 (3.5 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:ae:1d:63:30:2d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12685 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12685 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:982631 (982.6 KB)  TX bytes:982631 (982.6 KB)
```

`iwconfig` gives this:

```
bnep0     no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Post the output of `lspci | grep -i wireless`.

Comment: Hey green7. Its output is none. Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find everything about troubleshooting the wireless connections at this [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html).

If nothing helps, reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunatelly nothing helps. I didn't want reinstall as it is long process. But it seems there is no other way. I think my problem is related with Linux Kernel.

Comment: In that case, I think it's better to reinstall than playing around with kernel versions, just to save time.